# How to create cloudworks anaplan s3 connection

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, anaplan-api

How can we create s3 connection form Anaplan cloudworks, i know with IAM access key and secret access key we can make successful connection. but i need to create S3 connection from Anaplan Cloudworks without using IAM access key and secret access key. Is there any possibilities to make successful connection through like API, or IAM roles etc...

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use the Cloudworks API to create a connection, refer to this article: https://community.anaplan.com/discussion/97412/cloudworks-this-is-how-we-use-it-part-3-the-cloudworks-api/p1

However, I'm not sure if you can do it without an access key or secret access key.